# Android send extra Data through multiple Activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a chain of intents

1) Select File

2) Overlay some stuff

3) Save on Disk

4) Upload to Server

**This means that i am using those commands 4 times:**

```
video_id = extras.getString("video_id");
i.putExtra("video_id", video_id);'
```

Is there another neat way of doing that, without having to write anything on disc or db?

Comment: SharedPreferences? but not sure if you really require shared preferences for your use case. what is the problem using intents?

Comment: oh this looks fine, will the shared preferences be deleted when restarting the app properly?

Comment: No. SharePreferences is not for that use case. May be a sticky broadcast??

Comment: Oh is this kinda broadcast message which can be queried from every activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Singleton Class i.e. [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) in android. It maintains global application state.

```
public class GlobalClass extends Application{
    private String name;

    public String getName() {

        return name;
    }
}
```

Assign GlobalClass.java in application tag in application Manifest.xml `android:name="com.androidexample.globalvariable.GlobalClass"`

After Assigning you can set or access this variable from any activity using following code.

```
    final GlobalClass globalVariable = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();
    //Set name in global/application context
    globalVariable.setName("Android Example context variable");

   //get name frim global/application context from any other activity.
   String name = globalVariable.getName();
```

Comment: May i ask for a minimal example?

Comment: Sure i will just post it.

Comment: Seems to be the thing i need, can i pass custom Datastructures as well?

Comment: Yes, you can pass any type of data.

Comment: it is not for passing the data, generally it is using for holding data throughout the application context.

Comment: Thats exactly what i need, i will implement it and come later back

Comment: I will definetly after testing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreference. Please check  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html
SharedPreference will not delete automatically.

Comment: SharedPreferences is not for the use case described by op in the comments