# Android Navigation state perservation

Tags: android

Hi I'm working on a android app where I'm navigating from Activity A to Activity B and then to Activity C then to Activity D

Each Activity will pass some value to the next Activity and the Activity will use the value to setup the view. (i.e user id, project id).

In the manifest.xml I'm using android:parentActivityName and Meta-data android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY to setup the back button on the Action bar.

When I press the back button on Activity D, Activity C is recreated and the intent passed to Activity C is lost.  I know I can use android:launchMode="singleTop" to fix that.  But If i navigation from Activity D to Activity B, is there a way to preserve the value Activity received from Activity A?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) Singleton class in android. It maintains global application state.
Please refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31510191/android-send-extra-data-through-multiple-activities/31510305#31510305)